# Configuring multiple WSUS servers to all use windows update as download source

Tags: windows, windows-update, patch

I have 3 main sites, each have a WAN connection which is good but not great, and internet connections.

I have just built a WSUS 3.0 SP2 on windows 2008 R2 boxes in each region.

I want to configure one as the primary and the other 2 as downstream boxes, saving WAN/internet bandwidth.

There doesn't seem to be a way to configure these to 'report' into the main box, and download the approved patches without using the WAN link.
Is there some obvious setting I am missing, enabling these as replica does everything I need apart from the download source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite understanding how you're expecting a remote WSUS server to communicate with the primary except via the WAN link?

As far as configuring a WSUS server as a downstream server, that's covered in the WSUS Deployment Guide, and is presented in the setup wizard. (Option 1: Get updates from Microsoft; Option 2: Get updates from another WSUS server). See [Configure and Manage Replica Servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939885%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Your link pointed me in the right direction, I was happy for the boxes to communicate across the WAN, but download updates from the internet links. The last section of that link provided the info, Just wasnt looking in the right place.

Comment: We're trying to do the same. This helped us out: http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-configure-branch-office-wsus-server-get-approvals-centrally-download-updates-